# How to logout within one test in Laravel testing?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Laravel v5.7.1

I have multiple tests with same assertions and want to move them in one function and call it from tests. Here is example of function:

```
private function admin_only($url, $method = 'GET', $data = []) {
    // \Auth::logout();
    $response = $this->json($method, $url, $data);
    $response->assertStatus(401);
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user(),'api')->json($method, $url, $data);
    $response->assertStatus(403);

    $response = $this->actingAs($this->admin(),'api')->json($method, $url, $data);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
}
```

In this I firstly check for unauthenticated user and everything works as expected, but there are some functions, where API calls toggle some state, so I want to revert it back by calling function second time:

```
$this->admin_only('/api/service/toggle-state', 'POST', $data);
$this->admin_only('/api/service/toggle-state', 'POST', $data);
```

And second call in same test results in failure because first `$this->json()` used as admin and returns success code.

That `\Auth::logout()` supposed to solve problem, but instead throws error `BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.`

Solutions like "Separate test for second call", "No toggle revert", "Same response code for non-admin users and guests" should work, but seems wrong for me.

Comment: Did you try using `Auth` with `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and then `Auth::logout()` without the \ ?

Comment: Tried it just now, still same error.

Answer (score 7):

Luckily `RequestGuard` is `Macroable`, so we can extend it with our own methods. Try to do the following:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard;

// ...

RequestGuard::macro('logout', function() {
    $this->user = null;
});

$this->app['auth']->guard('api')->logout(); // or omit `->guard('api')` part
```

This is opposite of what `->actingAs` does. All the following requests will not have the authenticated user.

This can be added to the base test class as a method, and then used as `$this->actingAsGuest()` or something similar. Anyway, it would be convenient to have this by default in Laravel.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. You can also use the `Auth` facade to logout

Comment: @andrewtweber using the Auth facade for me results in the sam error.

Comment: Thank you Damir. While the answer itself lead me to the correct direction, it unfortunately didn't actually solve the issue. Then I found this detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/57941133/741782 from @patricus

Answer (score 0):

it might you have different guards >> so this might work

```
Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
```

you can change 'admin' to whatever the guard name

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I have 2 default laravel guards for auth, and this is `api` one `['middleware' => ['auth:api']`.   `\Auth::guard('api')->logout();` throws same error